# Copy Text From Textbox to Clipboard not working when deploy on iis Server ASP.net C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, iis

Hi guys  am trying to copy the text to clipboard using javascript in ASP.net and C# but its working fine in local when host in IIS server its not working please help me to fix the issue Thank you .
code  written below like in the t there is data

```
function copytoclipboard(t) {
  alert("t =" + t);
   const txt = t;
   navigator.clipboard.writeText(txt + 'xyz')
       .then(() => { alert(`Copied  123!`) })
       .catch((error) => { alert(`Copy failed! ${error}`) })
   return;
}
```

Comment: What are the errors you get in the chrome developer console when deployed in IIS Server?

Comment: Try using ctrl-F5 in the browser to refresh your cache.

Comment: no errors in console  Harshana Serasinghe

Comment: Was there any resolution to this? We're facing a similar issue.